# Id mapping for entities extending a base entity with a generic Id

Tags: java, generics, jpa

**Situation**: JPA 2.1, entities extending a **base entity with a generic id**.

Interface for an `Entity` with a generic id:

```
public interface Entity<ID extends Serializable> extends Serializable {
    public ID getId();
    public void setId(ID id);
}
```

Base implementation (abstract), defines some additional common attributes:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity<ID extends Serializable> implements Entity<ID> {

    private LocalDateTime creationTimestamp;
    private LocalDateTime lastModificationTimestamp;
    private Long version;
    private ID id;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Some concrete entities: `Person`, whose id is an `UUID` which gets assigned before persisting:

```
public class Person extends BaseEntity<UUID> {

    public Person() {
        setId(UUID.randomUUID());
    }
    // attributes, getters and setters
}
```

and `Address`, whose ids are `Long` and are generated by a sequence:

```
public class Address extends BaseEntity<Long> {
    // attributes, getters and setters
}
```

O/R-mapping:

```
<mapped-superclass class="idx.evaluation.jpa.hibernate.framework.BaseEntity">
    <attributes>
        <basic name="creationTimestamp">
            <column name="created" updatable="false" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="lastModificationTimestamp">
            <column name="last_modified" />
        </basic>
        <version name="version">
            <column name="version" />
        </version>
    </attributes>
</mapped-superclass>

<entity class="idx.evaluation.jpa.hibernate.model.Person">
    <table name="person" />
    <attributes>
        <id name="id">
            <column name="id" nullable="false" unique="true" />
        </id>
        <!-- more attributes -->
    </attributes>
</entity>

<entity class="idx.evaluation.jpa.hibernate.model.Address">
    <table name="address" />
    <attributes>
        <id name="id">
            <column name="id" nullable="false" unique="true" />
            <generated-value strategy="SEQUENCE" generator="id_sequence" />
        </id>
        <!-- more attributes -->
    </attributes>
</entity>
```

My IDE (Eclipse 4.5) issues a warning on the id attributes of `Person` and `Address`:
 *"Attribute "id" is inherited; referring to inherited attributes in the orm.xml may not be supported by all persistence 
 providers"*

When running tests, I get the following exception:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build entity manager factory
...
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException:
No identifier specified for entity: idx.evaluation.jpa.hibernate.model.Person
```

**Question**: how can I realize such a mapping, where the base class defines a generic Id attribute, but the Id is differently mapped/generated per subclass? 
I made another attempt by using `attribute-override` on the id, which worked for `Person` but not for `Address` (as I can't specify a `generated-value` for the override, but want to use a sequence there).

Any help/hints are appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by **splitting** the `BaseEntity` in two parts: one with the id (unmapped), and one with the metadata (creation/modification timestamps and version):

```
public abstract class EntityMetadata {
    private LocalDateTime creationTimestamp;
    private LocalDateTime lastModificationTimestamp;
    private Long version;
    // setters and getters
}

public abstract class BaseEntity<ID extends Serializable>
extends EntityMetadata implements Entity<ID> {
    private ID id;
    // setters and getters
}
```

The EntityMetadata mapping does not define the Id...

```
<mapped-superclass class="idx.evaluation.jpa.hibernate.framework.entity.EntityMetadata">
    <attributes>
        <basic name="creationTimestamp">
            <column name="created" updatable="false" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="lastModificationTimestamp">
            <column name="last_modified" />
        </basic>
        <version name="version">
            <column name="version" />
        </version>
    </attributes>
</mapped-superclass>
```

... allowing the `Person` and `Address` to define whatever Id they like (attribute named `"id"`, mapping to an arbitrary column with a generated value).

For the actual type of the generic ID to be recognized by JPA, the `getId()` method has to be overridden to narrow the result to the actual type:

```
public class Address extends BaseEntity<Long> {
    // ...
    @Override
    public Long getId() {
        return super.getId();
    }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From JPA point of view, you cannot define two identity strategies in the way you've described.

A differing solution may be to have a `BaseEntity` which is further subclassed with differing identity strategies like `IdentityBaseEntity` versus `SelfIdentifyingBaseEntity`.

From this point, your subclasses pick which identity parent class it wishes to subclass.

Comment: "you cannot define two identity strategies" Why? According JPA2.1 specification, you can (see my answer to this question).

Answer (score 1):

According [JPA 2.1. specifiaction](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html):

> **11.1.4 AttributeOverride Annotation**
>
> The AttributeOverride annotation is used to override the mapping of a
>   Basic (whether explicit or default) property or field or **Id** property
>   or field.  ...
>
> **12.2.3.15 association-override** 
>   The association-override subelement is additive to any AssociationOverride or AssociationOverrides
>   annotations on the entity. It overrides any AssociationOverride
>   elements for the same attribute name. If an association-override
>   subelement is present, and attributes or subelements of that
>   association-override subelement are not explicitly specified, their
>   default values are applied.

So, you should try something like this:

```
<entity class="idx.evaluation.jpa.hibernate.model.Person">
    <table name="person" />
    <attribute-override name="id">
         <column name="id" nullable="false" unique="true" />
    </attribute-override>
</entity>
```

or

```
<entity class="idx.evaluation.jpa.hibernate.model.Address">
    <table name="address" />
    <attribute-override name="id">
            <column name="id" nullable="false" unique="true" />
    </attribute-override>
    <attributes>
       <id name="id">
          <column name="id" nullable="false" unique="true" />
          <generated-value strategy="SEQUENCE" generator="id_sequence" />
       </id>
       <!-- more attributes -->
    </attributes>
</entity>
```

For more info, see [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/xml-overriding.html) example in hibernate manual

Comment: As stated in the question, this works for the Person, but not for the Address, as I cannot specify it as a generated value (sequence).

Comment: It doesn't matter, you can use attribute-override for Address

Comment: I fixed my post, see my example

Comment: It would be nice and natural to do it this way (already tried it), but regrettably it isn't supported:

According to the orm_2_1.xsd:
The 'generated-value' element can only occur inside an 'id' element, and the 'attribute-override' can only have the elements 'description', 'column' and 'name'.

See http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_1.xsd

Comment: Try to use attribute-override + <id name="id">, I fixed example in my post. When I use JPA annotation it's work, you can use  @ AttributeOverride Annotation + @ ID Annotation together.

Comment: Now the BaseEntity needs to define an <id name="id" /> for the attribute-override on Address to work, which results in an error: "An ancestor of this class has already defined the primary key. Primary key attributes may not be defined here."

Answer (score 1):

i get this question now. And the best solution is an annotation:

> @MappedSuperclass
>
> Designates a class whose mapping information is applied to the entities that inherit from it. A mapped superclass has no separate table defined for it.

Here's my code:

BaseEntity.java

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    public static final Timestamp DELETE_AT = Timestamp.valueOf("1970-01-01 00:00:00.0");

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "`created_at`")
    private Timestamp createdAt;
}
```

Account.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "`accounts`")
public class Account extends BaseEntity {

    private Short status;

    private String email;
}
```

This code is ok.

As time goes by, hope this can help others